# Is an Empty Table for implementing Reverse Polymorphism and ActiveRecord::Base okay?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-schema

I have spent a lot of thought on this situation and cannot figure out what the best modeling system is:

There is a `Test`. A test can have a variety of of `TestItems`. These `TestItems` can (currently) consist of `TrueFalseQuestions`, `MultipleChoiceQuestions`, `ShortAnswerQuestions`, and `TestInfo`.

All of the models will implement some sort of `Printable` module. They will all be printable, but each model handles its printing in a different way. All models will also have a position as they are sortable in relation to all other models. All models can belong to a test.

All models of type `XXXQuestion` will print numbers when they print. The `TestInfo` will not do that.

`MultipleChoiceQuestions` will have `Answers` as children.

I have tried creating a `TestItem` class that uses reverse polymorphism and a shareable question module:

```ruby
class TestItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  belong_to :item, polymorphic: true

  db_fields: :main_text, :position, :item_id, :item_type

  def sort(params)
    ...
  end
end

module QuestionPrintable
  def get_print_number
    ...
  end

  def print
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

module Question
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      include QuestionPrintable

      has_one :test_item, as: :item, dependent: :destroy
      delegate :test, :main_text to: :test_item
    end
  end
end

class MultipleChoiceQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Question

  has_many :answers

  def print
    number = get_print_number
    ...
  end
end
```

This would work, except that some models (like `TrueFalseQuestion`) would not actually expand the `TestItem` class. They would have no extra information in the `TrueFalseQuestions` table, but they *would* implement methods unique to `TrueFalseQuestions`.  I realize I could also wrap a `TestItem` in a `TrueFalseQuestion` wrapper whenever it's instantiated but then I would need to store the kind of the question on the `TestItem` to know when to do that. So, in some sense, the `TrueFalseQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base` class is actually storing the kind implicitly just by existing. I don't know if that is a valid use of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

All the questions do share the printing features of a number (and several behaviors I anticipate needing, just not quite yet) that are not shared with other types of `TestItems` (i.e. `TestInfo`). Additionally, some `Question` types will store extra data right now. And I *believe* that all of them will store more data as this problem evolves. So I do think that abstraction is helpful. Is it okay to have an table that more or less exists to allow the implementation of a polymorphic ActiveRecord model?

Also, having the text on the `TestItem` prevents a crazy amount of joins to display the main text of all items for a test.

The big difficulty, is if I do this a different way (for example not having a `TestItem` class and just a bunch of shared modules or storing these all as `TestItems` with a `:kind` attribute), I need to start switching behavior on the class type or an attribute, and I try to avoid any code that tests on class type or has *so* much behavior switch based on a attribute value.

I think in general those solutions can be achieved with duck typing, which would work with my empty ActiveRecord class, but this one just has me puzzled.

EDIT:

Another solution that occurred to me, that would prevent switching on kind would be to use some sort of `kind` value in the `TestItem` and use it to create a wrapper:

```ruby
class TestItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test

  attr_accessor :main_text, :position, :kind

  def wrapped_object
    klass = kind.constantize
    klass.new(_needed_params)
  end
end

class TrueFalseQuestion # DO NOT INHERIT
  attr_accessor :kind, :position

  def print
    ...
  end
end
```

I left out the various modules to not distract from the general solution, those can be easily implemented.

So now my potential debate is:

1. Empty Database Tables

   - Positives:

     - No wrappers needed
     - More extendable in the future
   - Negatives:

     - It's an empty table....
     - [Possible YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)
2. Method that returns wrapped object

   - Positives:

     - Solves the immediate problem without introducing extra database tables
     - Allows for all the same abstractions in the previous solution
   - Negatives:

     - Relies on the kind attribute (maybe not bad in this case?)
     - If the domain changes this could easily become too complex to maintain